# Package Dependency Rules?

Tags: ros, launch-file, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I read in this document [p05-ros-navigacija.pdf](http://www.fer.unizg.hr/_download/repository/p05-ros-navigacija.pdf)

Create Package with its dependency, then launch folder with launch file to load TurtleBot in simple office environment. Then when run `$ roslaunch ros_liv_turtlebot office_turtlebot.launch`

get this message

```
cannot locate [office_turtlebot.launch] in package [ros_liv_turtlebot]
```

I try to follow error

```
 amal@amal-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~/ros/sandbox/ros_liv_turtlebot$ roswtf
Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
Package: ros_liv_turtlebot
================================================================================
Static checks summary:

Found 1 warning(s).
Warnings are things that may be just fine, but are sometimes at fault

WARNING The following packages have msg/srv-related cflags exports that are no longer necessary
    <export>
        <cpp cflags="..."
    </export>:
 * dynamic_reconfigure: -I${prefix}/msg/cpp -I${prefix}/srv/cpp


Found 1 error(s).

ERROR The following packages have rpath issues in manifest.xml:
 * ros_liv_turtlebot: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * rosconsole: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * turtlebot_teleop: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * actionlib_msgs: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * nodelet_topic_tools: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * diagnostic_updater: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * rotate_recovery: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * nav_core: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * pcl_ros: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * nav_msgs: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * laser_geometry: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * clear_costmap_recovery: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * roscpp: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * roslib: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * voxel_grid: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * rostest: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * pcl: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * visualization_msgs: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * tf: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * nodelet: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * move_base: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * map_server: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * message_filters: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * joy: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * std_msgs: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * navfn: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * gmapping: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * costmap_2d: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * move_base_msgs: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * diagnostic_msgs: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * dynamic_reconfigure: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * bondcpp: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * pluginlib: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * base_local_planner: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * amcl: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * geometry_msgs: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * sensor_msgs: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * rosbag: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * actionlib: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * bond: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"

================================================================================
Beginning tests of your ROS graph. These may take awhile...
analyzing graph...
... done analyzing graph
running graph rules...
... done running graph rules

Online checks summary:

Found 1 warning(s).
Warnings are things that may be just fine, but are sometimes at fault

WARNING The following node subscriptions are unconnected:
 * /rosout:
   * /rosout
```

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56081/package-dependency-rules-?!/) by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2013-02-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-02-24**:
Please update your question to show how you currently refer to that package.

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2013-02-24**:
OK, I see now I have to change Q at all

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-02-25**:
Is your $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH set correctly? What does `rospack find ros_liv_turtlebot` display?

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2013-02-25**:
amal@amal-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~$ rospack find ros_liv_turtlebot
/home/amal/ros/sandbox/ros_liv_turtlebot
:
yes, I am sure that package path is set correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. This looks like your homework. In general, you should do your own homework.
2. Re-read pages 5 and 6 carefully.
3. The error you're seeing indicates that roslaunch can't find a file named `office_turtlebot.launch` anywhere inside of the `ros_liv_turtlebot` package.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2013-02-26**:
1- it is not a homework, ROS is my self study to do my graduation project..
2- page 5 and 6 where ?!
3- yes, I know that it can not find the launch file, but this file is exist so why it can not find it ?!

Thanks

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2013-02-27**:
Pages 5 and 6 of the document you linked to describe how to create the appropriate launch file. If the file exists, there's probably something wrong with your directory structure; can you add a recursive directory listing to the question?